Longest complete subsequence of ordered vowels

Given a string made up of "a", "e", "i", "o", or "u", find the longest subsequence of vowels in order. For example, is the string is "aeiaeiou", then the answer is 6, making the subsequence "aaeiou". Another example is: "aeiaaioooaauuaeiou" where the answer is 10. A complete subsequence means that you need to have all the vowels in order, a -> e -> i -> o -> u, but you can have repeats of vowels like "aaeeeeiiooouuu" is valid. If no such subsequence exists, return 0.

I came up with a DP approach of O(n^2) and I'm curious if there is a faster version for this problem.
def find_longest_dp(vowels):
    n = len(vowels)
    dp = [[0, False] for _ in range(n)]
    prev_vowel = {"a": None, "e": "a", "i": "e", "o": "i", "u": "o"}

    for i in range(n):
        if vowels[i] == "a":
            dp[i] = [1, True]
        
        for j in range(i):
            if dp[j][1] and vowels[j] in {vowels[i], prev_vowel[vowels[i]]}:
                dp[i][0] = max(dp[i][0], dp[j][0] + 1)
                dp[i][1] = True
    
    return max((dp[i][0] for i in range(n) if vowels[i] == 'u'), default=0)


@RobbyCornelissen here is full problem https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-of-all-vowels-in-order/description/

@RobbyCornelisse Subsequence, not substring (contiguous)

@sahasrara62 But leetcode problem is about contiguous substrings

@RobbyCornelissen No, the question does not lack clarity. A subsequence is a very clearly defined term, and the OP never claims that the question comes from leetcode.

What does the "complete" in your title mean? There's nothing like that in the quoted specification.

Please tell the meaning of dp[i] to help understand your code.

And if "complete" means that all five vowels need to appear in the subsequence, then what if no such subsequence exists? Your code returns 0 then, but that's not in the quoted specification.

Added some context in my question, but "complete" means that the subsequence should have all of [a, e, i, o, u] and they should be ordered. Something like "aaaeeioou" is valid but "aeiuo" is not.

O(n) by keeping track of the max length for each last-of-the-subsequence vowel (e.g., maxlen[3] tells the max length of an ordered subsequence ending with 'o'):
def find_longest_dp2(vowels):
    maxlen = [0] * 5
    for v in vowels:
        i = 'aeiou'.find(v)
        maxlen[i] = max(maxlen[:i+1]) + 1
    return max(maxlen)

Or if all five vowels need to be in the subsequence (as the "complete" in your title suggests) and you want 0 if no such subsequence exists (as your code suggests):
def find_longest_dp3(vowels):
    maxlen = [0] + [float('-inf')] * 5
    for v in vowels:
        i = '.aeiou'.find(v)
        maxlen[i] = max(maxlen[i-1:i+1]) + 1
    return max(maxlen[5], 0)

Attempt This Online! with testing.
